# Pillow Not installing on Apple Silicon

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I am having a nightmare of a time installing Pillow on my apple silicon. Everytime I attempt to install it, it throws a truly massive error which I have posted below. It says wheel is not installed but it is installed. It also says to refer to the Pillow page which I have done. I also installed homebrew and tried it that way. I really like this labtop and the m1 chip but if I need Pillow and python to work. Can anyone help me??

```
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-8.1.0.tar.gz (44.9 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for Pillow, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: Pillow
    Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/myname/PycharmProjects/WestCorp/venv2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-install-7aau8lns/pillow_2e71e6817697421fbee1ad980c7f610f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-install-7aau8lns/pillow_2e71e6817697421fbee1ad980c7f610f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-record-6pvy22mf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/myname/PycharmProjects/WestCorp/venv2/include/site/python3.9/Pillow
         cwd: /private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-install-7aau8lns/pillow_2e71e6817697421fbee1ad980c7f610f/
    Complete output (174 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-install-7aau8lns/pillow_2e71e6817697421fbee1ad980c7f610f/setup.py", line 865, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/WestCorp/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/WestCorp/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/WestCorp/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-install-7aau8lns/pillow_2e71e6817697421fbee1ad980c7f610f/setup.py", line 702, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-install-7aau8lns/pillow_2e71e6817697421fbee1ad980c7f610f/setup.py", line 922, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/myname/PycharmProjects/WestCorp/venv2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-install-7aau8lns/pillow_2e71e6817697421fbee1ad980c7f610f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-install-7aau8lns/pillow_2e71e6817697421fbee1ad980c7f610f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/rl/5f06x3b503j2g7rg4xq_3kzr0000gn/T/pip-record-6pvy22mf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/myname/PycharmProjects/WestCorp/venv2/include/site/python3.9/Pillow Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Try `pip3 install --no-cache-dir pillow`

Comment: Thank you for that, but it also errored out :'(

Comment: Are you sure you've ran `pip3 install wheel`? Because the error msg says it isn't installed...

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that this is something that is broken with the new apple silicon/python 3.9 universal install. I have installed python 3.8 and I was able to install pillow just fine. but for whatever reason pillow is not recognizing the images properly, so if I use pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img) it returns as nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue on a M1 machine, running pip inside a VENV.

The solution appeared to be simple, I needed to upgrade pip:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands it will definitely work:-

(1)   import sys

(2)   !{sys.executable} -m pip install matplotlib

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this works for you. try this.

> Go to the **Application** folder -> Right-click on **Terminal** App ->
> **Get Info**
>
> Tick **Open with Rosetta** option.

try now.